# spritebuilder game + apportable load FATAL ERROR: RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h NOT found

Tags: load, apportable, revmob

I get the error below when executing the "apportable load" command on a game made with SpriteBuilder:

Check the error log below:

```
...   

    Compiling /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/IAPHelper.m
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    Compiling /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/KurrentapIAPHelper.m
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    Compiling /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/MyiAd.m
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    1 error generated.
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    Compiling /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/GADHelper.m.o] Error 1
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/IAPHelper.m.o] Error 1
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/ABGameKitHelper/ABGameKitHelper.m.o] Error 1
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/KurrentapIAPHelper.m.o] Error 1
    1 error generated.
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/MyiAd.m.o] Error 1
    In file included from <built-in>:169:
    In file included from <command line>:20:
    /Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/Prefix.pch:20:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
    #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.kurrentap.HappyBird/Users/icarlitux/Documents/KURRENTAP/GIT/GAMES/HappyBird/HappyBird.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m.o] Error 1
    scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Any thoughts? I'm stuck with this error and unable to generate the APK for Android.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Make sure you have the [Apportable Indie SDK](http://www.apportable.com/pricing). Ad networks are not available in the Starter version
- Make sure that RevMobAds is in your installation

  ```
  ~  $ ls -dl ~/.apportable/SDK/System/RevMobAds/
  drwx------  12 paulb  staff  408 Mar 18 17:11 /Users/paulb/.apportable/SDK/System/RevMobAds/
  ```
- Make sure that RevMobAds is in Release.final

  ```
  ~/apps/Spin (master) $ grep -r RevMobAd Spin.approj/targets
  Spin.approj/targets/Spin/Release.final:        "RevMobAds"
  ```
- If not add it to the deps section of add_params in configuration.json

  ```
  ~/apps/Spin (master) $ grep -r RevMobAds Spin.approj/configuration.json
  Spin.approj/configuration.json:        "RevMobAds"
  ```

Note: The examples above are for the [Spin sample app](https://github.com/apportable/Spin). Replace ~/apps/Spin with the directory where your app's .xcodeproj is.

Comment: I will give it a try after download the indie trial SDK, I think that must be the issue.